# node.js tracing on performance api produces no events

Tags: node.js, performance, trace

Per the node.js docs on tracing, setting a `node.perf` category should emit trace events from the `perf_hooks::performance` API. However, no such events are emitted.

Below, you can see me instantiate the tracing instance and use 2x performance APIs.

When running the script (`node --trace-event-categories node,node.async_hooks,node.perf --trace-event-file-pattern 'trace_${pid}-${rotation}.json' foo.js`), tracing files are produced, but no events are contained within with matching `node.perf` `"cat"`s.

```js
// foo.js
const trace_events = require("node:trace_events");
const { performance, createHistogram } = require("perf_hooks");

const tracing = trace_events.createTracing({ categories: ["node.async_hooks", "node.perf"] });
tracing.enable();

console.log(trace_events.getEnabledCategories());

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function slowMark() {
  performance.mark("started");
  await sleep(50);
  performance.mark("ended");
  performance.measure("work", "started", "ended"); // expect tracing event for this line
}

async function slowWork() {
  console.log("slow start");
  await sleep(500);
  console.log("slow finish");
}

async function main() {
  await slowMark();
  await performance.timerify(slowWork)(); // expect tracing event for this line
  tracing.disable();
}

main();
```

Am I misunderstanding the docs?

- tracing: https://nodejs.org/api/tracing.html
- performance: https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooksperformance
- example tracing file, matching the script and CLI cmd above: https://gist.github.com/cdaringe/f01bf00a9d8ed3805562221a67c614a8